# Add domain to home server

Tags: linux, dns, nginx

I bought myself a second computer as my home server and installed ubuntu server 20.04. I also purchased a dedicated IP from my provider. My server is connected via a router, I gave it a static IP 192.168.5.5 inside the router's network and configured port forwarding.

I checked that according to my IP that the provider gave me, you can now see my site that I launched for the test.

Next, I plan to buy several domains and create several small sites on my server. I would also like to be able to use subdomains.

I have absolutely no experience in setting up servers, what should I do? Perhaps there are articles that fit my purpose? I hope for your help

Comment: Your question is off-topic unfortunately, I recommend that you google some tutorials, then come back when you have specific questions.

Answer (score 1):

You need to setup a web server like Nginx or Apache on your Ubuntu server. After that you need to point the domain name you buy from the DNS provider to your fix IP address.

There is [a tutorial on setting up Apache server on Ubuntu server](https://www.answertopia.com/ubuntu/setting-up-an-ubuntu-web-server/) to get you started. But you can also google it yourself.